# cant use ctable inside a coreUI component in angular

Tags: angular, dashboard, core-ui

I'm using coreUI to make a admin dashboard.
I've downloaded coreui, installed the project and dipendences.
Ok, I'd like to make a new page into the dashboard.

I've execute the command:
ng generate component catalogue.

in my catalogue.component.ts I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TableModule, UtilitiesModule } from '@coreui/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalogue',
  templateUrl: './catalogue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalogue.component.scss']
})
export class CatalogueComponent implements OnInit {
  catalogueItems: any[] = [
    { name: "Prodotto 1", description: "Descrizione prodotto 1", price: "10€",availability: "Disponibile", image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300", moreActions:["sfilettato","intero"] },
    { name: "Prodotto 2", description: "Descrizione prodotto 2", price: "20€",availability: "Disponibile", image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300", moreActions:["sfilettato","intero"] },
    { name: "Prodotto 3", description: "Descrizione prodotto 3", price: "30€",availability: "Non Disponibile", image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300", moreActions:["intero"] },
  ];


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

this is my html:

```
<app-dashboard>
    <table  [striped]="true" ctable>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Descrizione</th>
            <th>Prezzo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of catalogueItems">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</app-dashboard>
```

and that is in the app.module.ts:

```
import { CatalogueComponent } from './catalogue/catalogue.component';

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true,
};
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...APP_CONTAINERS, CatalogueComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
...
```

my actual problem is that once i go to the catalogue:

```
{
    path: 'catalogue',
    component: CatalogueComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Catalogue'
    }
```

the page gives me this error:

```
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'striped' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.

2     <table  [striped]="true" ctable>
```

If i remove the striped attribute, then the table is shown, but is just like a normal html table, is not a ctable.

Anyone can lead me in the right direction with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the free template for CoreUI, try going to the "app.module.ts" and adding the `TableModule` to the imports. For some reason, when you get the repo, it is not there by default:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AvatarModule,
    BreadcrumbModule,
    FooterModule,
    DropdownModule,
    GridModule,
    HeaderModule,
    SidebarModule,
    IconModule,
    NavModule,
    ButtonModule,
    FormModule,
    UtilitiesModule,
    ButtonGroupModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SidebarModule,
    SharedModule,
    TabsModule,
    ListGroupModule,
    ProgressModule,
    BadgeModule,
    ListGroupModule,
    CardModule,
    NgScrollbarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TableModule, //add this for table directives
  ],
  providers: [
```